# Get Static Member of Parent Class from Child Inherited Class

Tags: c#, class

Let's say I have,

```
public class A
{
    public static void MyAMethod()
    {
    }

    public class B
    {

    }        
}

public class C : A.B
{
    public void MyCMethod()
    {
        MyAMethod();// I need to call this
    }
}
```

Now I need to call MyAMethod from  class C.

**Edit**: In my situation class A is unavailable. So, I cannot use A.MyAMethod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the IL code for

```
namespace NestedTest
{
    public class A
    {
        public static void MyAMethod()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("public static void MyAMethod()");
        }

        public class B
        {
            public void MyBMethod()
            {
                MyAMethod();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you will find that `MyBMethod` is implemented(?) as

```
.method public hidebysig instance void  MyBMethod() cil managed
{
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  call       void NestedTest.A::MyAMethod()
  IL_0006:  nop
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method B::MyBMethod
```

As you can see the call to **NestedTest.A**::MyAMethod() is hard-coded i.e. the "magic" was already done by the C#->IL compiler. (*)
You could get the information you need to call the static method via reflection, e.g. (without error handling and rather crude)

```
public class C : A.B
{
    public void MyCMethod()
    {
        Type parent = GetType().BaseType;
        Type outer = parent.DeclaringType;
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = outer.GetMethod("MyAMethod");
        mi.Invoke(null, null);
        return;
    }
}
```

but there is probably a better solution for your specific problem.

---

(*) and the c# compiler does that only as specified in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx

> 3.7 Scopes

The scope of a name is the region of program text within which it is possible to refer to the entity declared by the name without qualification of the name [...]

- The scope of a member declared by a class-member-declaration (§10.1.6) is the class-body in which the declaration occurs. In addition, the scope of a class member extends to the class-body of those derived classes that are included in the accessibility domain (§3.5.2) of the member.

`class B` is part of the class-body of class A, `class C` is not. And `class C` is also not derived from class A.

Answer (score 4):

You can just call `A.MyAMethod()` from inside your method since it is static

Comment: I know I can do this but I need to call this directly. For example, inside class B I can directly call MyAMethod.

Comment: That is because you are inheriting from B and not A. So you have to call it like you would any other static method

Comment: In my situation class A is unavailable. So, I cannot use A.MyAMethod. The class C is dynamically generated by a framework (inheriting it with B). class A is unavailable for me.

Comment: Don't quite follow... If your class has A.B then A must be available. Are you saying class C is entirely generated dynamically and you can't change the implementation of `MyCMethod`?

Comment: Yes. The framework which I am using is generate class dynamically by inheriting the class with A.B. I can only directly call the static members of A.B. So I am thinking whether it is possible to call the member of class A. The class is dynamically generated and I can add my own custom methods in there. Similar like ASP.NET which generates class dynamically, but I can add my own methods in this class.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do

```
public class C : A.B
{
    public void MyCMethod()
    {
        A.MyAMethod();// I need to call this
    }
}
```

As the method is static you can call it from anywhere through class A

Answer (score 0):

You set MyAMethod to be static, so just call `A.MyAMethod()` inside your MyCMehtod()

Regards

Answer (score 0):

A static method, field, property, or event is callable on a class even when no instance of the class has been created. And according to the data given in [Staic Members Functions](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/04/c-static-members/). You can call a static members directly with the Class name. So, in your case

`A.MyAMethod();` will do the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `MyAMethod()` that way directly cause it doesn't belong to `class B` and you are inheriting class B; instead it's a static member of  `class A` and Hence you have to qualify it before calling `A.MyAMethod();`

If you would have inherited `class A` instead then your code would do fine cause class C will inherit the method as well.

OR

Change your code to accomodate what you want like

```
public class A
    {
        public static void method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("method in base class");  
        }
    public class B
    {
        public void bmethod()
        {
            A.method(); 
        }
    }
}

public class C : A.B
{
    public void cmethod()
    {
        bmethod(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to call this directly. See the above comments